# Update attribute in XSL for-each

Tags: pdf, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

At work I've been given the fun task of generating PDFs with XSL. The XML structure I'm working with is similar to

```
<records>
    <topLevel>
        <topLevelID></topLevelID>
        <secondLevel>
            <secondLevelID></secondLevelID>
            <thirdLevel>
            </thirdLevel>
            <thirdLevel>
            </thirdLevel>
        </secondLevel>
    </topLevel>
    <topLevel>
        <topLevelID></topLevelID>
        <secondLevel>
            <secondLevelID></secondLevelID>
            <thirdLevel>
            </thirdLevel>
            <thirdLevel>
            </thirdLevel>
        </secondLevel>
    </topLevel>
</records>
```

I would try to give a more meaningful example of the XML, but I don't feel like approaching any legal boundaries that may exist. With that XML structure, I have to output a block of text in the PDF for every `thirdLevel` node. The XSL I have so far is like

```
<xsl:for-each select ="topLevel">          
    <xsl:variable name="topID" select="topLevelID"/>
    <xsl:for-each select ="secondLevel">
        <xsl:variable name="secondID" select="secondLevelID"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="thirdLevel">            
            <fo:block-container position="absolute" height="12.8pt" width="220.8pt" left="160pt" display-align="auto">
                <xsl:attribute name="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(193 + [whatshouldgohere]), 'pt')"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <fo:block font-size="7pt">                          
                    <xsl:call-template name="insertThirdLevel"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Basically, I need to add some value to the top attribute to make the text for each `thirdLevel` node appear on its own line. I've tried using combinations of adding/multiplying by the ID (starts at 1 and increases by 1 for each set) and `position()`, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: "concat((193*position()), 'pt')" should work, how were you doing multiplication?

Comment: The issue I ran into is that I basically have three different positions that I could use for the three different for-each levels. Also, with the way the data is laid out in the XML, just using position() seems to cause the text to output on top of other text at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should really look into `<xsl:apply-templates>`, it can save you a lot of typing.

Simplified version:

```
<xsl:variable name="line-height" select="10" />

<xsl:template match="/records">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//thirdLevel" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="thirdLevel">
  <xsl:variable name="top" select="193 + position() * $line-height" />
  <fo:block-container top="{concat($top , 'pt')}">
    <fo:block font-size="7pt">                          
      <xsl:call-template name="insertThirdLevel"/>
    </fo:block>
  </fo:block-container>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="insertThirdLevel">
  Third Level!
</xsl:template>
```

Simplified output ("fo" namespace excluded):

```
<fo:block-container top="203pt">
  <fo:block font-size="7pt">
    Third Level!
  </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
<fo:block-container top="213pt">
  <fo:block font-size="7pt">
    Third Level!
  </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
<fo:block-container top="223pt">
  <fo:block font-size="7pt">
    Third Level!
  </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
<fo:block-container top="233pt">
  <fo:block font-size="7pt">
    Third Level!
  </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was overthinking this a lot. Thanks for simplifying it for me.